# Add code what worked in prestashop 1.6 in Prestashop 8

Tags: php, prestashop

I had in prestashop order list backoffice a code showning the estimated date of delivery. It worked in PS 1.6.X but in Prestashop 8 AdminOrdersControllers.php was changed and now i dont know how add my code, I resume the code:

controllers/admin/AdminOrderController.php (old PS 1.6.x)

In:

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->bootstrap = true;
        $this->table = 'order';
        $this->className = 'Order';
        $this->lang = false;
        $this->addRowAction('view');
        $this->explicitSelect = true;
        $this->allow_export = true;
        $this->deleted = false;

        parent::__construct();

        $this->_select = '
```

I added then:

```
(SELECT (DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(op.`date_add`,INTERVAL 7 + IF((WEEKDAY(DATE_ADD(op.`date_add`, INTERVAL 7 DAY)) IN (5)), 2, 0) + IF((WEEKDAY(DATE_ADD(op.`date_add`, INTERVAL 7 DAY)) IN (6)), 1, 0) DAY), "%W, %e of %M")) FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'order_payment` op WHERE op.`order_reference` = a.`reference` limit 1) as DayOfDelivery,
```

then after of:

```
$this->fields_list = array(
            'id_order' => array(
                'title' => $this->trans('ID', array(), 'Admin.Global'),
                'align' => 'text-center'
            ),
```

I added:

```
'DayOfDelivery' => array(
                'title' => $this->l('Day Of Delivery'),
                'align' => 'center',
                'orderby' => false,
                'search' => false,
                'class' => 'fixed-width-xs',
                'callback' => 'getIsDayOfDelivery'
            ),
```

then I added a function:

```
public function getIsDayOfDelivery ($a, $order)
    {
        if ($order['note']) {
            return '<span title="" data-toggle="tooltip" class="label-tooltip" data-original-title="'.$order['note'].'" data-html="true" data-placement="top"><i class="icon-truck"></i></span>';
        } 
        else {
            return '<span title="" data-toggle="tooltip" class="label-tooltip" data-original-title="'.$order['DayOfDelivery'].'" data-html="true" data-placement="top"><i class="icon-truck"></i></span>';
        }
    }
```

Do you know how add this code in src/Core/Grid/Definition/Factory/OrderGridDefinitionFactory.php or in src/PrestaShopBundle/Controller/Admin/Sell/Order/OrderController.php or in what file should be added?

Answer (score 0):

In order to do things properly consider building a [very basic module](https://devdocs.prestashop-project.org/1.7/modules/creation/tutorial/) that relys on one of the hooks that were added in Prestashop 1.7.7 in backoffice order page after Symfony migration  (check "[Order view page layout modifications](https://devdocs.prestashop-project.org/1.7/modules/core-updates/1.7.7/)" in this help page) so you can move and display your already existing code there.